# Part of custom taxonomies show the rest don't(WP)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I made custom taxonomies on wordpress and only the first 3 work and the last one for some reason. I have no idea why this is so, I copied the first one that worked and pasted it about 8 times changing all the names/singular names and slugs.

My code:
http://pastebin.com/MEfDrU08

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to it, the taxonomies had names to similair to eachother.